# "-bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied" when logging in

Tags: linux, bash

I have this server running Centos 7.
Every time I log in (remotely or locally) with every user I get an error.
If I log in as root I get

```
-bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

If I log in as a normal user I get

```
-bash: /home/normal_user/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

The permission for the .bashrc is

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   176 Dec 29  2013 .bashrc
```

And its content is

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Can't figure out what is going on. Plus everything is working as intended.

EDIT:
@terdon

```
[root@dmbi-va ~]# grep -F .bashrc /root/.profile /root/.bash_profile /root/.bash_login /etc/profile /etc/bashrc
grep: /root/.profile: No such file or directory
/root/.bash_profile:if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
/root/.bash_profile:    . ~/.bashrc
grep: /root/.bash_login: No such file or directory
```

@roaima @ikkachu

```
[root@dmbi-va ~]# ls -Zld /etc /etc/bashrc .bashrc
-rw-r--r--.   1 system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 root root  176 Dec 29  2013 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x. 139 system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       root root 8192 Jun 21 09:37 /etc
-rw-r--r--.   1 system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       root root 2835 Aug 12  2015 /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `grep -F .bashrc /root/.profile /root/.bash_profile /root/.bash_login /etc/profile /etc/bashrc`. It looks like something is attempting to execute (instead of source) `/root/.bashrc`.

Comment: @terdon FYI, OP hasn't said which distribution they're using; with Red Hat-based distros, bash is compiled to source `/etc/bashrc` on start-up.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan ah, I see. I didn't know that, thanks. I edited my previous comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: That dot in the end of the permission bits hints at SELinux. Perhaps `ls -Z` might tell something

Comment: My guess that profile tries to execute it instead of sourcing. So there is a `.bashrc` line instead of `. .bashrc` in the profile. If it affects all users maybe look into /etc/skell as well

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, getting `bash: 404: command not found` right after login.

Long story short, this was because a few days earlier, I made a typo while installing **docker-compose** :

- one of the install commands is `curl -L https://[...long URL...] -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose`
- this command downloads some bash completion rules and stores them into `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose`, which is included automatically when Bash starts, by reading `/etc/bash_completion.d/*`
- since I made a typo in the `[...long URL...]` part, I requested a non-existing URL, and anything **curl** received was a `404 not found` error message, which ended into `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose`
- after that, any time I logged in, `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose` was sourced, and trying a "command" such as `404 not found` logically caused the `bash: 404: command not found` error.